# If the Fourier transform of a signed measure is identically zero, is the same true of the measure?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I am trying to prove the following seemingly obvious fact:

Let $\mu$ be a finite signed measure on $\mathbb R$. Suppose that $\hat\mu(u) = \int_\mathbb R e^{iux} d\mu(x) = 0$ for all $u$. Then $\mu(E) = 0$ for all measurable sets $E$.

However, I have not yet met with much success. First of all, is this actually true? And, if so, how can I prove it?

Comment: Most analysis textbooks that discuss Fourier transforms for measures will have a proof of this.  I think Folland does, for example.  Why not visit your library and then ask here if you have questions about what you see?

Comment: I just checked Folland, and it does not appear to have a proof of this fact. I also tried searching a couple of different versions of my question on google, and none yielded a site that had a proof. If you could send me a link to a proof somewhere, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a sketch of a proof.  The details are for you to fill in.

1. If $f$ is continuous and periodic with some period $M$, then $\int f d\mu = 0$.  (Stone-Weierstrass theorem.)
2. If $f$ is continuous and compactly supported, then $\int f d\mu = 0$.  (Approximate $f$ by periodic functions with very long period.)
3. If you know the Riesz representation theorem, you are done.  If not, show that $\mu((a,b))=0$ for all intervals $(a,b)$ by approximating $1_{(a,b)}$ by continuous functions.  Then show that $\mu(U) = 0$ for all open sets $U$.  Use a monotone class or $\pi$-$\lambda$ argument to show that $\mu(A)=0$ for all Borel sets $A$.

Comment: How is the 1.) the case? Don't $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ have these properties, but their integrals are not zero?

Comment: @jablesauce Note we are working under the hypothesis that $\mu$ is a measure such that $\int e^{iux} \mu(dx) = 0$ for all $u$.  Then $\int \sin(x) \mu(dx) = \frac{1}{2i}\left(\int e^{ix}\mu(dx) + \int e^{-ix} \mu(dx)\right) = 0$ applying our assumption with $u=1$ and $u=-1$.  So indeed, for such a measure $\mu$ we do have that the integral of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are zero.  (Since it turns out that $\mu$ is the zero measure, this is not surprising.)

Comment: Understood, thanks! What did you mean exactly when you wrote $u=1$ and $u=−1$ ?

Comment: @jablesauce: When you apply $\int e^{iux} \mu(dx) = 0$ with $u=1$ it says $\int e^{ix} \mu(dx) = 0$, and when you apply it with $u=-1$ it says $\int e^{-ix} \mu(dx) = 0$.

Comment: Sorry my mistake and didn't notice the $u$ in the integral in your previous comment. Thanks again!