# Convex subset of real normed space is the intersection of halfspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a normed real space and $G$ a closed convex subset of $A$.

> How do I show that $G$ is the intersection of all the closed halfspaces in $A$ containing $G$?

What I know:
A halfspace is $H_{f,c}=\{a\in A: f(a)\leq c\}$ for $f\in A^*$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$. So I want to show that $G=\bigcap_{f\in A^*,G\subset H_f}H_f$.
What we want thus, is to show that $\bigcap_{f\in A^*,G\subset H_f}H_f\subset G$, since clearly $G\subset \bigcap_{f\in A^*,G\subset H_f}H_f$.
Further we know for all $a,b\in G$ that for all $\lambda\in[0,1]$ we have $\lambda a+(1-\lambda)y\in G$. How do I use these to prove the statement?

Edit: The separation theorem states: for a real or complex normed space $X$ with $A,B\subset X$ non-empty and disjoint convex sets we have
1. $A$ is open $\implies$ $\exists f\in X^*,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $$\Re f(a)<\gamma\leq\Re f(b)$$ for $a\in A,b\in B$
2. $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed $\implies$ $\exists f\in X^*,\gamma\in\mathbb{R},\delta>0$ s.t. $$\Re f(a)\leq\gamma-\delta<\gamma+\delta\leq\Re f(b)$$ for $a\in A,b\in B$.

Comment: You need more. A form of the Hahn-Banach separation theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer I put it in the question, but how would I use that?

Comment: Let $A$ a point outside $G$, and $B = G$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Let $x$ be that point outside $G$, then by 2. I have that $\Re f(x)=f(x)\leq\gamma-\delta<\gamma+\delta\leq\Re f(g)=f(g)$ for $g\in G$. How does that help exactly?

Comment: I didn't see that your definition of a half-space is wrong. You must allow arbitrary values as the criterion, $H(f;c) = \{ x : f(x) \leqslant c\}$ ($f(x) < c$ for an open half-space). [Otherwise $0$ would belong to every closed half-space, and you couldn't write every closed convex set as an intersection of (closed) half-spaces.]

Comment: @DanielFischer You are totally right, Im sorry

Comment: @DanielFischer Does that mean I should not be looking at the separation theorem?

Comment: Do you then see how it follows that $x$ doesn't belong to the intersection of all half-spaces containing $G$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm afraid I don't see that, why is that?

Comment: Take the linear functional provided by 2, and multiply it with $-1$. Compare to the definition of a half-space.

Comment: @DanielFischer Do we then have that $-f(x)\geq \delta-\gamma$?

Comment: Yes. And what have we for $(-f)(g)$ where $g\in G$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Then $(-f)(g)\leq-\delta-\gamma$, but I fear that I do not see where this is headed to

Comment: Look at $\{ a \in A : -f(a) \leqslant -\gamma\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So $g\in \{a\in A:-f(a)\leq\gamma\}$?

Comment: $G \subset \{a \in A : -f(a) \leqslant -\gamma\}$ and $x\notin \{a\in A : -f(a) \leqslant -\gamma\}$

Comment: @DanielFischer And that means that $G=\bigcap H$?

Comment: It means $x \notin \bigcap H$. From that, you make another step to arrive at the desired conclusion.

Comment: @DanielFischer What is the last step?

Comment: Using that $x \in A \setminus G$ was arbitrary.

Comment: @DanielFischer Than you for your help. I am going to post an answer based on your help, could you please have a look once it is posted?

Comment: Sure, can do that.

Comment: @DanielFischer I posted an answer, could you let me know if you agree with it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in A\backslash G$. Since $\{x\}$ is compact and $G$ is closed, we have (by part 2 of the separation theorem) that there exist $f\in X^*$, $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\delta>0$ such that
$$f(x)\leq\gamma-\delta<\gamma+\delta\leq f(g)$$
for $g\in G$.
Then we see that $-f(x)\geq\delta-\gamma$. So $x\notin H_{-f,-\gamma}=\{a\in A:-f(a)\leq-\gamma\}$.

Let $g\in G$. Then $-f(g)\leq\gamma-\delta$, so we have $g\in H_{-f,-\gamma}=\{a\in A:-f(a)\leq-\gamma\}$.

Since all points outside of $G$ are not element of a halfspace and all elements of $G$ are, we find that $G=\bigcap \{H_{f,\gamma}:f\in A^*,\gamma\in\mathbb{R},G\subset H_{f,\gamma}\}$.

Comment: The intersection is not over all $f$ and $\gamma$, it's only over those with $G \subset H_{f,\gamma}$. Writing that as an intersection is a bit cumbersome. One can write $$\bigcap_{\substack{f\in A^{\ast}, \gamma \in \mathbb{R} \\ G \subset H_{f,\gamma}}} H_{f,\gamma},$$ but that's a bit heavy. $$\bigcap_{G \subset H_{f,\gamma}} H_{f,\gamma}$$ is not strictly correct, but clear enough to be interpreted correctly. Formally correct is also $\bigcap \{ H_{f,\gamma} : f \in A^{\ast}, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}, G \subset H_{f,\gamma}\}$.

Comment: The final sentence is, apart from the issue mentioned above, not detailed enough. At a point where that sentence suffices, you don't really need to say anything. Say for example "Thus $x \notin \bigcap\limits_{G\subset H_{f,\gamma}} H_{f,\gamma}$. Since $x\in A\setminus G$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\bigcap\limits_{G\subset H_{f,\gamma}} H_{f,\gamma} \subset G$. Since the inclusion in the other direction is clear, we have equality."

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your help!