# Doubt about the demonstration of the uniqueness of the Fourier transform of a measure

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-transform, riesz-representation-theorem

For a project at my University, I have to prove that in the space of real numbers, if the Fourier transform of a measure is zero, then the measure is zero. I found a post with a solution to this problem

[If the Fourier transform of a signed measure is identically zero, is the same true of the measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84805/if-the-fourier-transform-of-a-signed-measure-is-identically-zero-is-the-same-tr)

but I don't understand how to do step two, if anyone could help me with the demonstration I would be very grateful, I have the following sketch of proof

Let $\mu$ be a signed measure. Assuming $\hat \mu (u) = \int exp(iux) d \mu (x) = 0$

1. > If $f$ is continuous and periodic with some period $M$, then $\int f d\mu = 0$. (Stone-Weierstrass theorem.)

If $f$ is continuous and periodic, we have that by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, there is a sequence of trigonometric polynomials $P_n$ that approximate $f$ for $n$ large enough, then by the dominated convergence theorem $$\int P_n d \mu \to \int f d \mu$$ and as $P_n$ can be expressed as the integral of exponential functions, the integral $\int P_n d \mu$ becomes zero, as it converges to $\int f d \mu$, the last integral is also zero

2. > If $f$ is continuous and compactly supported, then $\int f d\mu = 0$. (Approximate $f$ by periodic functions with very long period.)

I have trouble proving this step, can it be said that if $f$ is continuous and compactly supported, then it can be approximated by periodic functions? I don't know a result that justifies that

3. By the Riesz theorem, we have that $F$ linear functional with locally compact support can be represented as $F(f) = \int f d \mu$, with $\mu$ unique for all $f$, taking $F=0$ we have that $\mu = 0$ and again by the Riesz theorem $|F|=|\mu|$ implies that $\mu = 0$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $f$ has support inside $(a,b),$ let $g$ be the $(b-a)$-periodic function which coincides with $f$ on $[a,b].$ Then $0=\int gd\mu=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}\int fd\mu$ hence $\int fd\mu=0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I just understood it, thank you very much.

Comment: @MarkViola Indeed: if $\forall n\in I, a_n=a$ and $\sum_{n\in I}a_n=0$ then $a=0.$

Comment: ? Whence my reply.