# Uniqueness of Fourier transform of a measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-transform, dual-spaces

Let $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the space of real-valued continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ that vanish at infinity. By Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem, the dual of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ composed of all the real-valued regular Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$. For any $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the Fourier transform of $\mu$ is defined by
$$
\hat\mu(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-ix^\top\xi}d\mu(x),\quad\xi\in\mathbb{R}^d. 
$$
My question is, if $\hat\mu(\xi)=0$ for each $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^d$, could we draw the conclusion that $\mu$ is zero measure? I find some literature saying that it is true when $\mu$ is a finite measure, namely $\mu(\mathbb{R}^d)<\infty$. So are all the measures in $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ finite?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84805/if-the-fourier-transform-of-a-signed-measure-is-identically-zero-is-the-same-tr

Comment: Thanks for the link. And I also find that the following link could be related. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461217/if-the-fourier-transform-of-a-measure-is-zero-then-the-measure-is-zero?noredirect=1&lq=1    So it seems that for finite measures, the conclusion holds. And I am still curious that whether all the measures in $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ are finite. If not, would the conclusion be true for any measure in $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Comment: @Mittens From the link, I see that it still requires **finite** signed measure.

Comment: Of course finite signed measures are require. If you are not familiar with Tham then do a search for the Fourier inversion formula for measures. Usually presented in probability textbooks; Durrett for example. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84805/121671) is a posting in several variables but the idea is the same for  one variable

Comment: @Mittens Thank you. And is it true that all the measures of the space $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ are finite?

Comment: yes, finite (signed or nonnegative)

Comment: @Mittens But I find from the text book, for example, a course in functional analysis by John Conway, that the measure in $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is real-valued regular Borel measures. And the "finite" is not mentioned. Also I check other textbook and wiki. It seems like they donot mention "finite" when speaking of $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. May I have a reference about the "finite" which is explicitly written when talking about $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Thank you!

Comment: Fourier transform of infinite measures is not defined. the measures must be of finite total variation.

Comment: @Mittens That is what I am concerned. So is the Fourier transform well-defined on the whole space $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: For each $t\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and any finite positive measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\phi_t(x)=e^{-ix\cdot t}\in L_1(\mu)$. For any Borel signed measure of finite total variation (or a complex Borel measure) $\nu$, $\phi_t$ is also integrable with respect to $\nu$ (or rather the variation $|\nu|$) Furthermore, $|\int e^{ix\cdot t}\nu(dx)|\leq|\nu|(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: @Mittens So can I say that any measure $\nu$ in $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is finite? since $|\nu(\mathbb{R}^n)|\leq|\nu|(\mathbb{R}^n)=\|\nu\|_{\mathrm{TV}}<\infty$.  Thank you!